# how can i save a succulent from white mold?

Tags: succulents, mold

It got this white mold a couple days ago. Is it possible to save it?
[image]

Comment: My instinctive response would be to cut it off well above the damage (at least 3 rows of bumps, looking at the picture and still just instinctive) and try to re-root it in sterile (or healthy) soil/potting medium. But I don't *know* if that will work for your particular plant. If, as it appears, that's a pot with drainage inside a pot with no drainage, I'd also forget that arrangement for the future - seems popular with "designers," kills a lot of plants. Can be made to work if you religiously drain the excess water from the outer pot, but if you forget, very easy to make things way too wet.

Answer (score 2):

Scrape as much of it as you can off with a spoon or plastic without damaging the plant too much. Next apply a fungicide. You can either use an all-purpose fungicide or simply spray your succulent with a mild solution of bicarbonate of soda (baking soda), using 1/2 teaspoon per gallon of water. You can dab it on, but spraying is best. This [natural copper fungicide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000UJVDXY) is useful for many kinds of fungi and is safe for most plants.

Ideally, you should repot your plants after applying fungicide otherwise you risk re-infection, but plants can still recover without repotting.